# Using Lambda function as notification receiver for Chime SDK Meetings?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-chime-sdk

When creating a Chime SDK Meeting, one of the possible notification configurations is a Lambda function ARN (here [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/chime-sdk-meetings/client/create_meeting.html)):

```
response = client.create_meeting(
    ...
    NotificationsConfiguration={
        'LambdaFunctionArn': 'string',
        'SnsTopicArn': 'string',
        'SqsQueueArn': 'string'
    }
    ...
```

I would assume that means I can give it the ARN of a Lambda function, and that function will be invoked whenever an event happens. Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to be the case. My function receives no notifications about any meeting events.

The only [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime-sdk/latest/APIReference/API_meeting-chime_NotificationsConfiguration.html) about this feature is fairly cryptic:

> **LambdaFunctionArn**
> The ARN of the AWS Lambda function in the notifications configuration.

Is "in the notifications configuration" significant here? Do I need to create some "notifications configuration" somewhere else to be able to use this? Or am I perhaps missing some permissions I need to set up (e.g. allow Events Bridge to invoke my function)? Or am I misunderstanding this setting completely?